# can any one provide me example of Two_line_list_item in Android?

Tags: android, listactivity

Can any one provide me two_line_list_item example?

Comment: [Here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html) you can find an example. This style gives you an item with two rows of text, possibly with different formatting.

Comment: It is not a TwoLineListItem view, this tutorial is using simple ListView.

Answer (score 37):

I have yet to find an example that actually uses the built-in layout, `android.R.layout.two_line_list_item` and a `ListView` insted of `ListActivity`.  So here goes.

**If you're in a hurry, the `TwoLineArrayAdapter.getView()` override below is the important part of using the default `two_line_list_item` layout.**

## Your data

You have a class that defines your list items.  I'll assume you have an array of these.

```
public class Employee {
    public String name;
    public String title;
}
```

## An abstract TwoLineArrayAdapter

This abstract class can be reused, and makes defining a two-line `ListView` much easier later.  You *can* supply your own layout, but the two argument constructor uses the built-in `two_line_list_item` layout.  **The only requirement for custom list item layouts is that they must use `@android:id/text1` and `@android:id/text2` to identify their `TextView` children, just as `two_line_list_item` does.**

```
public abstract class TwoLineArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
        private int mListItemLayoutResId;

        public TwoLineArrayAdapter(Context context, T[] ts) {
            this(context, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ts);
        }

        public TwoLineArrayAdapter(
                Context context, 
                int listItemLayoutResourceId,
                T[] ts) {
            super(context, listItemLayoutResourceId, ts);
            mListItemLayoutResId = listItemLayoutResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.View getView(
                int position, 
                View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (null == convertView) { 
                listItemView = inflater.inflate(
                    mListItemLayoutResId, 
                    parent, 
                    false);
            }

            // The ListItemLayout must use the standard text item IDs.
            TextView lineOneView = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(
                android.R.id.text1);
            TextView lineTwoView = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(
                android.R.id.text2);

            T t = (T)getItem(position); 
            lineOneView.setText(lineOneText(t));
            lineTwoView.setText(lineTwoText(t));

            return listItemView;
        }

        public abstract String lineOneText(T t);

        public abstract String lineTwoText(T t);
}
```

## A concrete TwoLineArrayAdapter

Finally, here's the code you write specific to your Employee class so that it'll render in your `ListView`.

```
public class EmployeeArrayAdapter extends TwoLineArrayAdapter<Employee> {
    public EmployeeArrayAdapter(Context context, Employee[] employees) {
        super(context, employees);
    }

    @Override
    public String lineOneText(Employee e) {
        return e.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String lineTwoText(Employee e) {
        return e.title;
    }
}
```

## Activity.onCreate()

In your Activity's `onCreate()` method, you'll have code that looks like this:

```
    employees = new Employee[...];
    //...populate the employee array...

    employeeLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.employee_list);
    employeeLV.setAdapter(new EmployeeArrayAdapter(this, employees);
```

Comment: awesome answer, thanks. might I suggest additionally implementing getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) so that it appears correctly in that context. Your implementation can simply be: return getView(...)