# Is there a way to update multiple TextView with ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

I have a list view that has multiple textview's like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a list of POJO's that has a `name` and `address` and I want each item in the list view to be populated with those values.

My POJO is like this:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  //getter setter
  public String toString() {return name;} 
}
```

**Question**

When I set the list adapter with my list how can I set both name and address?

Currently I'm doing this which is only setting the name:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Person>(MyActivity.this, R.layout.list_text, R.id.name, personList));
```

Comment: Why does your `ArrayAdapter` have a `Color` type if you are passing `personList`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo for examples sake. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should create a custom `adapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter`. The things you can do with an `ArrayAdapter` are limited.

Something like this:

```
public class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Person> data;
    private final int layoutResourceId;

    public PersonAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Person> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            ...
            ...
            holder.textView3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text3);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Person person = data.get(position);

        holder.textView1.setText(person.getName());
        holder.textView2.setText(person.getAddress());
        ...
        ...
        holder.textView3.setText(person.getEtc());

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        ...
        ...
        TextView textView3;
    }
}
```

Where `textView1`, `textView2` ... `textView-n` are all your text views. Set your adapter as follows:

```
setListAdapter(new PersonAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.list_text, personList));
```

*Note: I assume that your `personList` is a `List` type object. If it is an `Array` do let me know.*

Comment: This is a great answer. Couldn't find anything that worked as well as this!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [TwoLineArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109271/can-any-one-provide-me-example-of-two-line-list-item-in-android) by ESV, it's formatted for name and title but is almost exactly what you need.

Edit:

```
class StringHolder {
    public String text;
    public int viewId;
}
```

For a scenario of *n* strings, the solution is very similar. Create a custom `ArrayAdapter` of type `StringHolder[]` or `List<StringHolder>` depending on if this amount if fixed. In your `getView` you would loop through all `StringHolder` objects, call `findViewById`, and update the text content. Alternatively, you could simply use the index in the array/ list and map that to a view ID if they will remain consistent.

This is of course just one way to do this, there are many more and I'll leave the actual implementation as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks. However, the two line example I gave is just for the questions sake. I am looking, in general, how to do this. What might I do if in some scenario I have five TextViews

Comment: I think the general concept is still the same. Why not, instead of an adapter that hosts two strings, host a list of strings? Your ArrayAdapter would be one of type List<String>. Or if five is a fixed number, String[]. You can then choose to use the position in the array/ list as what determines which TextView to update, or create a simple object that holds a reference to a String and a View ID.