# Updating listView through a custom adapter in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I am attempting to create a messaging system in my android application. When the user goes into the the message fragment, I need to populate the message list with previous message. From what I've read the best way to do this is with a custom adapter.

Here is my Messaging adapter

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<message>  {
private final MessagesFragment context;
private final int layoutResourceId;
private final ArrayList<message> messages;

public MessageAdapter(MessagesFragment messagesFragment, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<message> messages) {
    super(null, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = messagesFragment;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.messages = messages;

}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder  holder = null;
    int direction = messages.get(i).userType;
    //show message on left or right, depending on if
    //it's incoming or outgoing

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((MessagesFragment)context).getLayoutInflater(); 

        int res = 0;
        if (direction == DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
            res = R.layout.message_right;
        } else if (direction == DIRECTION_OUTGOING) {
            res = R.layout.message_left;
        }    
        convertView = inflater.inflate(res, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }

     holder.txtMessage.setText(messages.get(i).message);
     holder.txtDate.setText(messages.get(i).time);

     return row;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView txtMessage;
    TextView txtDate;
}
```

}

I am calling this inside my onCreateView in my fragment.

```
        // Generates all of the messages
    ArrayList<message> messages = getMessages;
    View messagesView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView)messagesView.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(MessagesFragment.this, R.id.listMessages, messages));
    ...
```

My application is crashing whenever I enter the fragment. I've taken bits of pieces of example code and applied to my application, but I'm unable to get it to work. Any advice or obvious error I'm not seeing?

Comment: can you please put the crash log? and change "super(null, layoutResourceId);" to "super(messagesFragment.getActivity(), layoutResourceId);"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got your design the wrong way round - you have your MessageAdapter taking a fragment as a reference. Instead, your activity should create and use your fragment and in your fragment, instantiate your adapter and do whatever it should do e.g. retrieve message data a populate your list.
So the context of your activity is passed to your fragment - then use that same context to pass into the constructor of your custom adapter.

Comment: Well this is in my Fragment. My activity calls my fragment, and on the oncreate in the Fragment I attempt to set the adapter to the listView. What should I pass into my adapter? The guide I read from [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985668/is-there-a-way-to-update-multiple-textview-with-arrayadapter) passes in context, which is an activity. I changed it to my Fragment and eclipse suggested I change it to my MessageFragment.

Answer (score 0):

in your **fragment** change:

```
 listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(MessagesFragment.this, R.id.listMessages, messages));
```

to

```
 listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(MessagesFragment.this.getActivity(), R.id.listMessages, messages));
```

in your **adapter** change:

```
private final MessagesFragment context;

    public MessageAdapter(MessagesFragment messagesFragment, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<message> messages) {
        super(null, layoutResourceId);
        this.context = messagesFragment;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.messages = messages;
}
```

to

```
private final Context context;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<message> messages) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.messages = messages;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error from the Fragment change. Specifically MessagesFragment.getActivity().

Comment: Fixed it by using getActivity(); It runs, but still crashes.

Comment: @confusedProgrammer post the crash log please

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<message>  {
private final MessagesFragment context;
private final int layoutResourceId;
private final ArrayList<message> messages;

public MessageAdapter(MessagesFragment messagesFragment, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<message> messages) {
    super(null, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = messagesFragment;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.messages = messages;

}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder  holder = null;
    int direction = messages.get(i).userType;
    //show message on left or right, depending on if
    //it's incoming or outgoing

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((MessagesFragment)context).getLayoutInflater(); 

        int res = 0;
        if (direction == DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
            res = R.layout.message_right;
        } else if (direction == DIRECTION_OUTGOING) {
            res = R.layout.message_left;
        }    
        convertView = inflater.inflate(res, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
     //You have get tag every time else it will through NullPointerException
     holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
     holder.txtMessage.setText(messages.get(i).message);
     holder.txtDate.setText(messages.get(i).time);

     return row;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView txtMessage;
    TextView txtDate;
}
```

Check above code you are made some mistake which I have make correct.