# Relate data and ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, arraylist

My situation is this:

In my View `Highscore_zeigen` I´ve got an `ArrayList<Rangliste>` that I want to show. The whole thing is in `onPostExecute` of a thread that tries to get JSON data from an URL.

```
    ArrayList<String> gewinnernamen = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> gewinnerdatum = new ArrayList<String>();
    Rangliste r = new Rangliste("","");
    ArrayList<Rangliste> rangliste = new ArrayList<Rangliste>();
```

....

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(isOnline() == true){


            System.out.println("HIHIHIHIHHIHI " +result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             JSONArray jsonarray = null;
            try {
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Highscore_zeigen.this, "Ups! Bitte überprüfe deine Netzwerkverbindung! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 




            String namest = "";
            String datumst ="";
            try {
                jb = (JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i = 0; i <5;i++){

                try {
                    jb = (JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    namest = jb.getString("name");
                    datumst = jb.getString("datum");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                gewinnernamen.add(i, namest);
                gewinnerdatum.add(i, datumst);





                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            for(int is = 0; is<5; is++){
                r = new Rangliste(gewinnernamen.get(is), gewinnerdatum.get(is));
                rangliste.add(r);
            }
```

So the data I want to show now is in `rangliste`. Everything works fine but I don´t know how to show my data in my `ListView`. The ListView is in the layout file of Highscore_zeigen, I also have a layout for my row:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvGewinner"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

</ListView>
```

Here is my layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

So I have the data, I have a ListView and I also have a layout for my ListView. What I don´t know is how I can connect these three things so that the data is shown in my ListView.

Comment: So you just want to display your data as list on the screen?

Comment: As list on the screen with the given layout I posted..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **R.android.two_line_list_item** as described at the link below.
There are links to the examples, but the second answer explains pretty well.

[can any one provide me example of Two_line_list_item in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109271/can-any-one-provide-me-example-of-two-line-list-item-in-android)

**EDIT:**

The way I would do it, I would create a reference to the ListView accessible to the whole class (namely, to AsyncTask). Then in onPostExecute():

```
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGewinner);

    try {
        for(int i = 0; i <5;i++){
            ...
            namest = jb.getString("name");
            datumst = jb.getString("datum");
            ... 
            Rangliste[] ... // create your array
            ...
        }
        lv.setAdapter(new RanglisteArrayAdapter(this, rangliste);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you might need to convert your JSON into array
Here is your addapter:

```
public class RanglisteArrayAdapter extends TwoLineArrayAdapter<Rangliste> {
    public RanglisteArrayAdapter(Context context, Rangliste[] rangliste) {
        super(context, rangliste);
    }

    @Override
    public String lineOneText(Rangliste r) {
        return r.namest;
    }

    @Override
    public String lineTwoText(Rngliste r) {
        return r.datumst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don´t know where to call this SimpleAdapter code. Can you give me an example?

Comment: And what is YourAddapter? There are so many examples that I really lost the overview sorry+...